# Data not displaying in ListView but when opening a messenger app and interacting data will display

Tags: android, json, listview

Good day. I would like to ask why do my listView does not display the data after fetching the JSON response from the server. I thought the data did not fetch but when I saw the log cat, it was successfully fetched but not displayed in my listView.

But when I was chatting in messenger then I came back to my app the data was displayed. At first, I don't know the reason why the data suddenly appear. so I thought maybe it was delayed. so I try it again and wait for a couple of mins but nothing happens no data was displayed. Hope you can help me resolve this issue.

I waited for a couple mins and this is the result.

[image]
**Logcat**

```
12-25 21:00:48.809 7264-7264/com.sample.test D/MyAdapter: Cardview Elements
12-25 21:00:48.809 7264-7264/com.sample.test D/CardView Clicked: br code:  0
12-25 21:00:48.809 7264-7264/com.sample.test D/CardView Clicked: mem id:   202
12-25 21:00:48.809 7264-7264/com.sample.test D/CardView Clicked: sle code: 11
12-25 21:00:48.809 7264-7264/com.sample.test D/CardView Clicked: slc code: 13
12-25 21:00:48.809 7264-7264/com.sample.test D/CardView Clicked: slt code: 99
12-25 21:00:48.809 7264-7264/com.sample.test D/CardView Clicked: ref num:  531
12-25 21:00:48.822 7264-7269/com.sample.test I/art: Do partial code cache collection, code=23KB, data=30KB
12-25 21:00:48.823 7264-7269/com.sample.test I/art: After code cache collection, code=23KB, data=30KB
12-25 21:00:48.823 7264-7269/com.sample.test I/art: Increasing code cache capacity to 128KB
12-25 21:00:48.836 7264-7264/com.sample.test D/InputTransport: Input channel constructed: fd=66
12-25 21:00:48.836 7264-7264/com.sample.test D/ViewRootImpl@9eefd6b[Toast]: setView = android.widget.LinearLayout{7bab0c8 V.E...... ......I. 0,0-0,0} touchMode=true
12-25 21:00:48.852 7264-7264/com.sample.test D/AbsListView: Get MotionRecognitionManager
12-25 21:00:48.855 7264-7264/com.sample.test D/MotionRecognitionManager: mSContextService = com.samsung.android.hardware.context.ISemContextService$Stub$Proxy@e0baee3
12-25 21:00:48.858 7264-7264/com.sample.test D/MotionRecognitionManager: motionService = com.samsung.android.gesture.IMotionRecognitionService$Stub$Proxy@d4d0e0
12-25 21:00:48.858 7264-7264/com.sample.test D/MotionRecognitionManager: motionService = com.samsung.android.gesture.IMotionRecognitionService$Stub$Proxy@d4d0e0
12-25 21:00:48.861 7264-7347/com.sample.test D/NetworkSecurityConfig: No Network Security Config specified, using platform default
12-25 21:00:48.863 7264-7347/com.sample.test I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
12-25 21:00:48.863 7264-7347/com.sample.test I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
12-25 21:00:48.901 7264-7281/com.sample.test D/mali_winsys: EGLint new_window_surface(egl_winsys_display*, void*, EGLSurface, EGLConfig, egl_winsys_surface**, egl_color_buffer_format*, EGLBoolean) returns 0x3000,  [705x132]-format:1
12-25 21:00:48.909 7264-7264/com.sample.test D/AbsListView:  onsize change 
12-25 21:00:48.914 7264-7264/com.sample.test V/InputMethodManager: Starting input: tba=android.view.inputmethod.EditorInfo@440563f nm : com.sample.test ic=null
12-25 21:00:48.914 7264-7264/com.sample.test I/InputMethodManager: [IMM] startInputInner - mService.startInputOrWindowGainedFocus
12-25 21:00:48.917 7264-7264/com.sample.test D/InputTransport: Input channel constructed: fd=80
12-25 21:00:48.917 7264-7264/com.sample.test D/InputTransport: Input channel destroyed: fd=81
12-25 21:00:48.917 7264-7264/com.sample.test D/ViewRootImpl@9eefd6b[Toast]: MSG_RESIZED_REPORT: ci=Rect(0, 0 - 0, 0) vi=Rect(0, 0 - 0, 0) or=1
12-25 21:00:50.256 7264-7264/com.sample.test D/SLDTLFragment onResponse: SL Details Response: {"sl_details":{"error":false,"sl_row":[{"tr_type":"RJ","credit":"94.17","tr_date":"2017-12-11"},{"tr_type":"RJ","credit":"94.17","tr_date":"2017-11-30"},{"tr_type":"RJ","credit":"94.17","tr_date":"2017-11-15"},{"tr_type":"RJ","credit":"94.17","tr_date":"2017-10-31"},{"tr_type":"RJ","credit":"94.17","tr_date":"2017-10-15"},{"tr_type":"GJ","credit":"0.00","tr_date":"2017-10-09"}]}}
12-25 21:00:50.256 7264-7264/com.sample.test D/LoginActivity: SL Details -error attribute             : false
12-25 21:00:50.257 7264-7264/com.sample.test D/SLDTLFragment: SL Details -sl_row array           : [{"tr_type":"RJ","credit":"94.17","tr_date":"2017-12-11"},{"tr_type":"RJ","credit":"94.17","tr_date":"2017-11-30"},{"tr_type":"RJ","credit":"94.17","tr_date":"2017-11-15"},{"tr_type":"RJ","credit":"94.17","tr_date":"2017-10-31"},{"tr_type":"RJ","credit":"94.17","tr_date":"2017-10-15"},{"tr_type":"GJ","credit":"0.00","tr_date":"2017-10-09"}]
12-25 21:00:50.826 7264-7264/com.sample.test D/ViewRootImpl@9eefd6b[Toast]: dispatchDetachedFromWindow
12-25 21:00:50.846 7264-7264/com.sample.test D/InputTransport: Input channel destroyed: fd=66
```

When I open a messenger

Log cat

```
12-25 20:46:26.498 30768-30768/com.sample.test D/ViewRootImpl@19e90b4[MainActivity]: MSG_WINDOW_FOCUS_CHANGED 0
12-25 20:46:26.612 30768-30768/com.sample.test D/InputTransport: Input channel destroyed: fd=80
```

After Clicking the chatbox

**Log cat**

```
12-25 21:01:19.336 7264-7264/com.sample.test D/ViewRootImpl@8eff987[MainActivity]: MSG_RESIZED: ci=Rect(0, 72 - 0, 750) vi=Rect(0, 72 - 0, 750) or=1
12-25 21:01:19.370 7264-7264/com.sample.test D/SLDTL Adapter GetView: Trans type: android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView{49a666a V.ED..... ......ID 0,0-0,0 #7f0800a3 app:id/sl_desc}
12-25 21:01:19.370 7264-7264/com.sample.test D/SLDTL Adapter GetView: Trans amount: android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView{ee175b V.ED..... ......ID 0,0-0,0 #7f0800c5 app:id/trans_amount}
12-25 21:01:19.370 7264-7264/com.sample.test D/SLDTL Adapter GetView: Trans date: android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView{bdfdbf8 V.ED..... ......ID 0,0-0,0 #7f0800c4 app:id/transDate}
12-25 21:01:19.379 7264-7264/com.sample.test D/SLDTL Adapter GetView: Trans type: android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView{6d7c10d V.ED..... ......ID 0,0-0,0 #7f0800a3 app:id/sl_desc}
12-25 21:01:19.379 7264-7264/com.sample.test D/SLDTL Adapter GetView: Trans amount: android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView{3bd58c2 V.ED..... ......ID 0,0-0,0 #7f0800c5 app:id/trans_amount}
12-25 21:01:19.379 7264-7264/com.sample.test D/SLDTL Adapter GetView: Trans date: android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView{b616d3 V.ED..... ......ID 0,0-0,0 #7f0800c4 app:id/transDate}
12-25 21:01:19.387 7264-7264/com.sample.test D/SLDTL Adapter GetView: Trans type: android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView{b2c5f3c V.ED..... ......ID 0,0-0,0 #7f0800a3 app:id/sl_desc}
12-25 21:01:19.387 7264-7264/com.sample.test D/SLDTL Adapter GetView: Trans amount: android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView{b5104c5 V.ED..... ......ID 0,0-0,0 #7f0800c5 app:id/trans_amount}
12-25 21:01:19.387 7264-7264/com.sample.test D/SLDTL Adapter GetView: Trans date: android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView{6513e1a V.ED..... ......ID 0,0-0,0 #7f0800c4 app:id/transDate}
12-25 21:01:19.395 7264-7264/com.sample.test D/SLDTL Adapter GetView: Trans type: android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView{4d7b327 V.ED..... ......ID 0,0-0,0 #7f0800a3 app:id/sl_desc}
12-25 21:01:19.395 7264-7264/com.sample.test D/SLDTL Adapter GetView: Trans amount: android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView{f9759d4 V.ED..... ......ID 0,0-0,0 #7f0800c5 app:id/trans_amount}
12-25 21:01:19.396 7264-7264/com.sample.test D/SLDTL Adapter GetView: Trans date: android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView{ec8077d V.ED..... ......ID 0,0-0,0 #7f0800c4 app:id/transDate}
12-25 21:01:19.402 7264-7264/com.sample.test D/SLDTL Adapter GetView: Trans type: android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView{a0c87be V.ED..... ......ID 0,0-0,0 #7f0800a3 app:id/sl_desc}
12-25 21:01:19.402 7264-7264/com.sample.test D/SLDTL Adapter GetView: Trans amount: android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView{3a5e01f V.ED..... ......ID 0,0-0,0 #7f0800c5 app:id/trans_amount}
12-25 21:01:19.402 7264-7264/com.sample.test D/SLDTL Adapter GetView: Trans date: android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView{ee40f6c V.ED..... ......ID 0,0-0,0 #7f0800c4 app:id/transDate}
12-25 21:01:19.403 7264-7264/com.sample.test D/AbsListView:  onsize change
```

After opening the app again

```
12-25 21:03:45.502 7264-7264/com.sample.test I/onResume: User is active. cancel timer
12-25 21:03:45.531 7264-7281/com.sample.test D/mali_winsys: EGLint new_window_surface(egl_winsys_display*, void*, EGLSurface, EGLConfig, egl_winsys_surface**, egl_color_buffer_format*, EGLBoolean) returns 0x3000,  [1080x1920]-format:1
12-25 21:03:45.550 7264-7264/com.sample.test D/SLDTL Adapter GetView: Trans type: android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView{1156b90 V.ED..... ......ID 24,53-64,106 #7f0800a3 app:id/sl_desc}
12-25 21:03:45.550 7264-7264/com.sample.test D/SLDTL Adapter GetView: Trans amount: android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView{e44dc89 V.ED..... ......ID 928,49-1008,98 #7f0800c5 app:id/trans_amount}
12-25 21:03:45.550 7264-7264/com.sample.test D/SLDTL Adapter GetView: Trans date: android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView{979d48e V.ED..... ......ID 24,106-204,155 #7f0800c4 app:id/transDate}
12-25 21:03:45.551 7264-7264/com.sample.test D/SLDTL Adapter GetView: Trans type: android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView{ac82ccb V.ED..... ......ID 24,53-64,106 #7f0800a3 app:id/sl_desc}
12-25 21:03:45.551 7264-7264/com.sample.test D/SLDTL Adapter GetView: Trans amount: android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView{4e31ca8 V.ED..... ......ID 928,49-1008,98 #7f0800c5 app:id/trans_amount}
12-25 21:03:45.551 7264-7264/com.sample.test D/SLDTL Adapter GetView: Trans date: android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView{95e93c1 V.ED..... ......ID 24,106-204,155 #7f0800c4 app:id/transDate}
12-25 21:03:45.551 7264-7264/com.sample.test D/SLDTL Adapter GetView: Trans type: android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView{a2313f2 V.ED..... ......ID 24,53-64,106 #7f0800a3 app:id/sl_desc}
12-25 21:03:45.551 7264-7264/com.sample.test D/SLDTL Adapter GetView: Trans amount: android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView{2f6a43 V.ED..... ......ID 928,49-1008,98 #7f0800c5 app:id/trans_amount}
12-25 21:03:45.551 7264-7264/com.sample.test D/SLDTL Adapter GetView: Trans date: android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView{962d8c0 V.ED..... ......ID 24,106-204,155 #7f0800c4 app:id/transDate}
12-25 21:03:45.552 7264-7264/com.sample.test D/SLDTL Adapter GetView: Trans type: android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView{7ee3cb5 V.ED..... ......ID 24,53-64,106 #7f0800a3 app:id/sl_desc}
12-25 21:03:45.552 7264-7264/com.sample.test D/SLDTL Adapter GetView: Trans amount: android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView{fed2f4a V.ED..... ......ID 928,49-1008,98 #7f0800c5 app:id/trans_amount}
12-25 21:03:45.552 7264-7264/com.sample.test D/SLDTL Adapter GetView: Trans date: android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView{9a1debb V.ED..... ......ID 24,106-204,155 #7f0800c4 app:id/transDate}
12-25 21:03:45.559 7264-7264/com.sample.test D/SLDTL Adapter GetView: Trans type: android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView{c7c4184 V.ED..... ......ID 24,53-64,106 #7f0800a3 app:id/sl_desc}
12-25 21:03:45.560 7264-7264/com.sample.test D/SLDTL Adapter GetView: Trans amount: android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView{cf64d6d V.ED..... ......ID 928,49-1008,98 #7f0800c5 app:id/trans_amount}
12-25 21:03:45.561 7264-7264/com.sample.test D/SLDTL Adapter GetView: Trans date: android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView{fc45da2 V.ED..... ......ID 24,106-204,155 #7f0800c4 app:id/transDate}
12-25 21:03:45.576 7264-7264/com.sample.test D/SLDTL Adapter GetView: Trans type: android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView{2ac768f V.ED..... ......ID 0,0-0,0 #7f0800a3 app:id/sl_desc}
12-25 21:03:45.576 7264-7264/com.sample.test D/SLDTL Adapter GetView: Trans amount: android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView{1283d1c V.ED..... ......ID 0,0-0,0 #7f0800c5 app:id/trans_amount}
12-25 21:03:45.576 7264-7264/com.sample.test D/SLDTL Adapter GetView: Trans date: android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView{68bd25 V.ED..... ......ID 0,0-0,0 #7f0800c4 app:id/transDate}
12-25 21:03:45.577 7264-7264/com.sample.test D/AbsListView:  onsize change 
12-25 21:03:45.600 7264-7264/com.sample.test D/ViewRootImpl@8eff987[MainActivity]: MSG_WINDOW_FOCUS_CHANGED 1
12-25 21:03:45.601 7264-7264/com.sample.test V/InputMethodManager: Starting input: tba=android.view.inputmethod.EditorInfo@71710c6 nm : com.sample.test ic=null
12-25 21:03:45.601 7264-7264/com.sample.test I/InputMethodManager: [IMM] startInputInner - mService.startInputOrWindowGainedFocus
12-25 21:03:45.611 7264-7264/com.sample.test D/InputTransport: Input channel constructed: fd=74
```

The data displayed successfully in my listView.

[image]

This is my code for **SLDTLFragment.java**

```
public class SLDTLFragment extends Fragment {

    private List<SLDTLData> sldtlDataList=  new ArrayList<SLDTLData>();
    private SLDTLAdapter adapter;
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;

    public SLDTLFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(this.getContext());
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        String br_code = getArguments().getString("br_code");
        String client_id = getArguments().getString("client_id");
        String slc = getArguments().getString("slc");
        String slt = getArguments().getString("slt");
        String ref_no = getArguments().getString("ref_no");

//        Log.d("SLDTLFragment","br code: "+br_code);
//        Log.d("SLDTLFragment","client id: "+client_id);
//        Log.d("SLDTLFragment","slc: "+slc);
//        Log.d("SLDTLFragment","sle: "+sle);
//        Log.d("SLDTLFragment","slt: "+slt);
//        Log.d("SLDTLFragment","ref_no: "+ref_no);

        //Passing data to getSLDTL method..
        getSLDTL(br_code, client_id, slc, slt, ref_no);

        View rootView= inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_sldtl, container, false);

        //List
        ListView listView= (ListView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.fragment_sldtl_ListView);

        sldtlDataList= new ArrayList<>();
        adapter= new SLDTLAdapter(getActivity(), sldtlDataList);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

        return rootView;
    }

    private void getSLDTL(final String br_code, final String client_id,
                          final String slc, final String slt, final String ref_no){

        // Tag used to cancel the request
        String tag_string_req = "req_sldtl";

        pDialog.setMessage("Retrieving sl details ...");
        showDialog();

        StringRequest strReq= new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST,
                AppConfig.URL_SL_DETAILS, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                Log.d("SLDTLFragment onResponse", "SL Details Response: " + response.toString());
                hideDialog();

                try{
                    JSONObject jObj= new JSONObject(response.toString());
                    //                    boolean error= jObj.getBoolean("error");
                    if(!jObj.isNull("sl_details")){
                        JSONObject accountsObject = (JSONObject) jObj.get("sl_details");
                        // access individual json object thru jsonObject.get("FIELD_NAME")
                        Log.d("LoginActivity", "SL Details -error attribute             : " + accountsObject.get("error").toString());
                        JSONArray slArray = accountsObject.optJSONArray("sl_row");
                        // Check if its login data i.e. user present
                        if (slArray != null) {
                            JSONArray array = accountsObject.getJSONArray("sl_row");
                            // access individual json array thru jsonObject.getJSONArray("FIELD_NAME")
                            Log.d("SLDTLFragment", "SL Details -sl_row array           : " + accountsObject.getJSONArray("sl_row").toString());

                            for (int index=0; index < array.length(); index++) {
                                SLDTLData data= new SLDTLData();
                                JSONObject object = (JSONObject)array.get(index);

                                String tr_type= object.getString("tr_type");
                                // Log.d("SLDTLFragment", "SL Details -sle_code attribute       : " + tr_type);
                                String credit_debit= object.getString("credit");
                                // Log.d("SLDTLFragment", "SL Details -sle_code attribute       : " + credit_debit);
                                String tr_date= object.getString("tr_date");
                                // Log.d("SLDTLFragment", "SL Details -sle_code attribute       : " + tr_date);

                                // Log.d("SLDTLFragment", "SL Details -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------");

                                data.setSldtl_trans_type(tr_type);
                                data.setSldtl_credit_debit(credit_debit);
                                data.setSldtltrans_date(tr_date);

                                sldtlDataList.add(data);

                                data.getSldtl_trans_type();
                                data.getSldtl_credit_debit();
                                data.getSldtltrans_date();

//                                Log.d("SLDTLFragment", "Get SLDTL: "+ sl_data.getSldtl_trans_type());
//                                Log.d("SLDTLFragment", "Get SLDTL: "+ sl_data.getSldtl_credit_debit());
//                                Log.d("SLDTLFragment", "Get SLDTL: "+ sl_data.getSldtltrans_date());
                            }
                        }
                    }else{
                        // a new JSON string that doesn't have sl_summ as member variable so display it and write new handler code
                        Log.d("SLDTLFragment", "Unknown JSON String          : " + jObj.toString());
                    }
                }catch(JSONException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }//end onResponse
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Log.e(TAG, "SLDTL response Error: " + error.getMessage());
            }
        }){
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
                // Posting params to register url
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                params.put("br_code", br_code);
                params.put("client_id", client_id);
                params.put("slc_code", slc);
                params.put("slt_code", slt);
                params.put("ref_number", ref_no);

                return params;
            }
        };
        // Adding request to request queue
        AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(strReq, tag_string_req);
    }

    private void showDialog() {
        if (!pDialog.isShowing())
            pDialog.show();
    }
    private void hideDialog() {
        if (pDialog.isShowing())
            pDialog.dismiss();
    }
}
```

**SLDTLAdapter.java**

```
public class SLDTLAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

        private Activity activity;
        private LayoutInflater inflater;
        private List<SLDTLData> sl_data;


     public SLDTLAdapter(Activity activity, List<SLDTLData>sl_data){
         this.activity= activity;
         this.sl_data= sl_data;
     }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View ConvertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        Log.d("SLDTL Adapter GetView","");

//        if (inflater == null)     //
//            inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity
//                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
//
//        if (ConvertView == null)
//            ConvertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_sldtl_row, null);

        ConvertView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.fragment_sldtl_row, null);

        TextView sl_type = (TextView) ConvertView.findViewById(R.id.sl_desc);
        TextView trans_date = (TextView) ConvertView.findViewById(R.id.transDate);
        TextView trans_amount = (TextView) ConvertView.findViewById(R.id.trans_amount);
        TextView debitCredit = (TextView) ConvertView.findViewById(R.id.debitCredit);

        SLDTLData sl= sl_data.get(position);

        sl_type.setText(sl.getSldtl_trans_type());
        trans_amount.setText(sl.getSldtl_credit_debit());
        trans_date.setText(sl.getSldtltrans_date());


        Log.d("SLDTL Adapter GetView","Trans type: "    +sl_type);
        Log.d("SLDTL Adapter GetView","Trans amount: "  +trans_amount);
        Log.d("SLDTL Adapter GetView","Trans date: "    +trans_date);

        return ConvertView;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return  sl_data.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int i) {
        return sl_data.get(i);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i) {
        return i;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `adapter.notifyDatasetChanged` after adding items to list as in

```
for (int index=0; index < array.length(); index++) {
                                SLDTLData data= new SLDTLData();
                                JSONObject object = (JSONObject)array.get(index);

                                String tr_type= object.getString("tr_type");
                                // Log.d("SLDTLFragment", "SL Details -sle_code attribute       : " + tr_type);
                                String credit_debit= object.getString("credit");
                                // Log.d("SLDTLFragment", "SL Details -sle_code attribute       : " + credit_debit);
                                String tr_date= object.getString("tr_date");
                                // Log.d("SLDTLFragment", "SL Details -sle_code attribute       : " + tr_date);

                                // Log.d("SLDTLFragment", "SL Details -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------");

                                data.setSldtl_trans_type(tr_type);
                                data.setSldtl_credit_debit(credit_debit);
                                data.setSldtltrans_date(tr_date);

                                sldtlDataList.add(data);

                                data.getSldtl_trans_type();
                                data.getSldtl_credit_debit();
                                data.getSldtltrans_date();

//                                Log.d("SLDTLFragment", "Get SLDTL: "+ sl_data.getSldtl_trans_type());
//                                Log.d("SLDTLFragment", "Get SLDTL: "+ sl_data.getSldtl_credit_debit());
//                                Log.d("SLDTLFragment", "Get SLDTL: "+ sl_data.getSldtltrans_date());
                            }
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); //<----- this will refresh list immediately
```

Answer (score 0):

This kind of problem occurs in threading because you are setting your adapter in `listView` in foreground thread and you are adding your data in List in background Thread so to resolve this kind of problem is that just set Your listView adapter after fetching your data like:

```
// other stuf before json calling
    StringRequest strReq= new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST,
                    AppConfig.URL_SL_DETAILS, new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    Log.d("SLDTLFragment onResponse", "SL Details Response: " + response.toString());
                    hideDialog();

                    try{
                        JSONObject jObj= new JSONObject(response.toString());
                        //                    boolean error= jObj.getBoolean("error");
                        if(!jObj.isNull("sl_details")){
                            JSONObject accountsObject = (JSONObject) jObj.get("sl_details");
                            // access individual json object thru jsonObject.get("FIELD_NAME")
                            Log.d("LoginActivity", "SL Details -error attribute             : " + accountsObject.get("error").toString());
                            JSONArray slArray = accountsObject.optJSONArray("sl_row");
                            // Check if its login data i.e. user present
                            if (slArray != null) {
                                JSONArray array = accountsObject.getJSONArray("sl_row");
                                // access individual json array thru jsonObject.getJSONArray("FIELD_NAME")
                                Log.d("SLDTLFragment", "SL Details -sl_row array           : " + accountsObject.getJSONArray("sl_row").toString());

                                for (int index=0; index < array.length(); index++) {
                                    SLDTLData data= new SLDTLData();
                                    JSONObject object = (JSONObject)array.get(index);

                                    String tr_type= object.getString("tr_type");
                                    // Log.d("SLDTLFragment", "SL Details -sle_code attribute       : " + tr_type);
                                    String credit_debit= object.getString("credit");
                                    // Log.d("SLDTLFragment", "SL Details -sle_code attribute       : " + credit_debit);
                                    String tr_date= object.getString("tr_date");
                                    // Log.d("SLDTLFragment", "SL Details -sle_code attribute       : " + tr_date);

                                    // Log.d("SLDTLFragment", "SL Details -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------");

                                    data.setSldtl_trans_type(tr_type);
                                    data.setSldtl_credit_debit(credit_debit);
                                    data.setSldtltrans_date(tr_date);

                                    sldtlDataList.add(data);

                                    data.getSldtl_trans_type();
                                    data.getSldtl_credit_debit();
                                    data.getSldtltrans_date();
                                    callListAdapter();

    //                                Log.d("SLDTLFragment", "Get SLDTL: "+ sl_data.getSldtl_trans_type());
    //                                Log.d("SLDTLFragment", "Get SLDTL: "+ sl_data.getSldtl_credit_debit());
    //                                Log.d("SLDTLFragment", "Get SLDTL: "+ sl_data.getSldtltrans_date());
                                }
                            }
                        }else{
                            // a new JSON string that doesn't have sl_summ as member variable so display it and write new handler code
                            Log.d("SLDTLFragment", "Unknown JSON String          : " + jObj.toString());
                        }
                    }catch(JSONException e){
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }//end onResponse
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "SLDTL response Error: " + error.getMessage());
                }
            }){
                @Override
                protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
                    // Posting params to register url
                    Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    params.put("br_code", br_code);
                    params.put("client_id", client_id);
                    params.put("slc_code", slc);
                    params.put("slt_code", slt);
                    params.put("ref_number", ref_no);

                    return params;
                }
            };

        public void callListAdapter(){
        adapter= new SLDTLAdapter(getActivity(), sldtlDataList);
            listView.setAdapter(adapter);
            }
// other stuf
```

just try it . if any kind of problem just comment. thanks.